# Closure Completion in For Loop Swift

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, closures

I have a group of objects that all need to be validated. The validation requires the use of a closure.

I understand the closure can complete at anytime, so the for loop will have completed prior to all the closures. So putting something like reloadData after the for loop will not work.

**So, what is good method of knowing when all the closure code has been completed, for each object that has gone through the loop?**

I can call reloadData within the closure and up date one at a time - but would rather do it once they have all been completed.

My code

```
    for aClient in passedPossible {

        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(aClient[address], completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in
            if let placemarks = placemarks as? [CLPlacemark] {
                // found it do stuff
            }
            else {
                // do stuff as cannot find
            }
        })
    }

    // how to reload at the end of the for loop
    self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths for each geocoding callback.

But if you must use reloadData(), easiest solution is to count your geocoding jobs preventing reentrance.

Example:

```
var loading =   false

@IBAction func
Do( sender: AnyObject ) {

    if !loading {
        loading = true
        var w = 0
        for i in 0 ..< 10 {
            dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue() ) {
                println( i )
                if ++w == 10 {
                    self.loading = false
                    println( "It's time to call reloaddata!" )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

How about attaching something like job ids and put those in a list?

```
var jobIDs: [ Int ] =   []

@IBAction func
Do( sender: AnyObject ) {

    if jobIDs.count == 0 {
        for theJobID in 0 ..< 10 {
            jobIDs.append( theJobID )
            dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue() ) {
                println( "Doing job:\(theJobID)" )
                self.jobIDs.removeAtIndex( find( self.jobIDs, theJobID )! )
                if self.jobIDs.count == 0 {
                    println( "It's time to call reloaddata!" )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You may use 'aClient' as job ID.

Comment: Thanks, I was going to update to use tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths at some stage. I was hoping for a less messy solution than counting. Ill just do it at every back to keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I just used the counter method.

Each time the closure completes, increment the counter.

Then check if the counter == the number of items that need to be processed in the closure.

I'll show a UIView indicating processing / disable user input, and dismiss once all items have processed.